# Android sensor reading not returning all sensors

Tags: android, android-sensors

I have (or so I thought) cobbled together code that should allow me to take in all sensor data changes and output them to the logs. However, the only sensor I am getting is the light sensor (sensor #5).

Inside OnCreate:

---

```
{
sm = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    Log.i("aaa","---sensors on");
          sm.registerListener(sensorListener,sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ALL),SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);

    List<Sensor> typedSensors = sm.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);

    for(Iterator<Sensor> i = typedSensors.iterator(); i.hasNext();) 
    {
          Sensor item = i.next();
          Log.i("aaa","SENSOR: "+item.getName());
    }
}
```

### Other relevant code:

```
 private static SensorEventListener sensorListener=new SensorEventListener() {
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent e) {
              writeSensorLog(e.sensor.getType()+":"+e.values[0]);
        }

        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
          // unused
        }
      };

public static void writeSensorLog(String data)
{
Log.i("aaa","sensor string: "+data);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TYPE_ALL` is used to get the list of all sensors available in the device. To register all sensors call `getSensorList` and register each member of the list.

```
List<Sensor> sensors = sm.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);
for (Sensor sensor : sensors)
{
    sm.registerListener(sensorListener, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I have been staring at that forever